# Cross Object Field Update using trigger

Tags: trigger

I am attempting to update a custom Callable Contacts field on the Account object. The trigger will look at all contacts associated with an account, and contacts that have phone numbers will be included in the custom field. Contacts without phone numbers will not be counted. My solution was to basically look at all of the contacts associated with the account, and if any of their phone fields are not null I add them to a list. So far all of my logic appears to work.

When I system.debug the callableContacts list, the list size is the correct number of contacts. When I use system.debug(myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c);...the result is null even though it should be an integer value.

I am having trouble assigning the size of that list to the custom field on the account record. Please advise.

```
trigger CallableContacts on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete) {
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) {
    for (Contact myContact : Trigger.new) {
        if (myContact.Id != null) {
            List<Contact> acctFromRelatedContact = [SELECT   Id,
                                                             AccountId,
                                                             Account.Callable_Contacts__c,
                                                             Account.Industry                                                        
                                                      FROM   Contact
                                                     WHERE   Id = :myContact.Id
                                                     LIMIT   1];
            system.debug(acctFromRelatedContact);
            List<Contact> callableContacts = [SELECT    Id 
                                                FROM    Contact
                                               WHERE    (Phone != null
                                                  OR     AssistantPhone != null
                                                  OR     HomePhone != null
                                                  OR     OtherPhone != null)
                                                 AND    AccountId = :acctFromRelatedContact.get(0).AccountId];
            system.debug(callableContacts.size());
            accList = [SELECT Id,
                              Account.Callable_Contacts__c
                         FROM Account
                        WHERE Id = :myContact.AccountId];
            system.debug(accList);
            system.debug(myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c);
            
            if (myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c != null) {
                for (Account acc : accList) {
                    myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c = callableContacts.size();                        
                }
                update accList;                    
            }                  
        }                                     
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Apart from best practices not being implemented, the problem seems to be this line 

`if (myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c != null) {` 

because the `myContact.Account.Callable_Contacts__c` will always be null.

Comment: Why would it always be null? Apologies for the amateur code...I am still very new to Apex and am trying to learn it.

Comment: It's because the `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.old` contains only the current record's fields, not any related record fields (like Account)  so they are always null.

Comment: ok, well I put that if statement in there to avoid the null pointer reference. how do I update  the field without getting the null pointer exception?

Comment: Your code will require restructuring. I can help but by tomorrow. It's night here.

Comment: Basically trigger.new context variable will only hold the information at the contact level in your contact trigger if you need to access the values of the related parent records you will have to explicitly query those records in your trigger code.
Please go through below link it will help you understand the trigger context variables and some other best practices.

https://www.iterativelogic.com/salesforce-apex-trigger-best-practices/